# Batch Job Error - Can't pass <Set> into execute method?

Tags: apex

I am working on a batch class and in my start method I have a "Set" of contact Ids.  I want to use this Set in the execute method of the batch job, but I am getting some errors shown below.   How would I modify my code to resolve this error.

I tried modifying the Database.Batchable to Database.Batchable, but that did not work.

```
global class CustomerBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowCallouts {

  global Set<Id> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   Set<Id> customerIds = new Set<Id>();
   Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE customer_overdue__c = TRUE];
   for( Contact c : contacts ) {
    customerIds.add(c.Id);
  } 
  if( customerIds.size() > 0) {
   return customerIds;
  }
  return null;
 }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, Set<Id> customerIdList) {
  System.debug('Customer Id List ---> ' + customerIdList);
 }

 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
 }

} // end batch class
```

**The errors I am getting are these:**

Class CustomerBatch must implement the method: System.Iterable Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext)

Class CustomerBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sets [are not iterable in Apex](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI). You can use a Set to accumulate a unique collection of Ids, and then convert to a `List<Id>`, which is iterable:

```
global class CustomerBatch implements Database.Batchable<Id>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {

  global Iterable<Id> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   Set<Id> customerIds = new Set<Id>();
   Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE customer_overdue__c = TRUE];
   for( Contact c : contacts ) {
    customerIds.add(c.Id);
  } 
  if( customerIds.size() > 0) {
   return new List<Id>(customerIds);
  }
  return null;
 }
```

Note that you also must change the signature of `execute()` to match the interface:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Id> customerIdList) {
```

It is *most likely* a better strategy, though, just to query Contacts in your `start()` method instead of working with iterators. Let Salesforce deal with acquiring and managing the complete scope of the batch job.

Your `execute()` method can re-query records to acquire related data or whatever you require. Note also that unless you are building a managed package, there is no need to use `global`; your class should be `public`.

```
public class TestQ318103 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE customer_overdue__c = TRUE]);
  }

 public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope) {
  System.debug('Customer Id List ---> ' + scope);
 }

 public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The start method has a defined signature that cannot be altered. What you are looking for is a parameterized constructor

```
global class CustomerBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowCallouts {

Set<ID> ids;
public CustomerBatch(Set<Id> ids){
 this.ids = ids;
}
```

You can use the set in you start or execute method.
Aee more here https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/06/passing-parameter-to-batch-apex-in.html?m=1

Comment: In my start method, I make an api call to get the Ids from an external system.  I then want to use these Ids to query the Contact object.  I understand the constructor can accept an argument but I am trying to return a "Set" in the start method.  Is this not possible? It allows me to return a List for some reason, but not a set?

Comment: The start method can either return a list of iterable type or a query locator. That the contract specified by batchable. You can always return a list and convert it to a set but even if you return a list the only difference you will get is it will order but you won't be able to use set methods on it